# How to retrieve a variable of type GeoCoordinate from app settings? Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to save the pushpins on a map to app settings so that they are loaded after the app closes, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the variable from storage. Does anyone know how I would achieve loading the pushpins back onto the map after they are saved?

This is what I have tried so far, I save the pushpins to Isolated Storage after they are added to the map in `OnNavigatedTo`

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLat") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLong") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("pName"))
            { 
                    var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"]);
                    var longtitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"]);
                    var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longtitude);
                    var pushPinName = NavigationContext.QueryString["pName"];

                    DrawPushPin(MyGeoPosition, pushPinName);
                    appSettings.Add("pushPin", MyGeoPosition);      

            }

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

And then I try to retrieve the pushpins when the page is loaded like this, but the following errors are thrown. I understand that `MyGeoPosition` is only seen within OnNavigatedTo so I cant reference it,is there an alternative method of retrieving it? :

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyMap.MapElements = (var)appSettings[MyGeoPosition];
        }

Error   1   The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaratio 
Error   2   The name 'MyGeoPosition' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you added the location to appSettings using the key "pushPin" you want to use the same key to retrieve that app setting. You also need to cast it to GeoCoordinate, not 'var'.

```
private GeoCoordinate MyGeoPosition;    

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyGeoPosition = (GeoCoordinate)appSettings["pushPin"];
}
```

Comment: `MyGeoPosition doesn't exist in the current context` the problem is MyGeoPosition is only visible in OnNavigatedTo method.How do I make it global so it can be used anywhere in the class?

Comment: Define MyGeoPosition outside of a particular functions scope and it'll be accessible anywhere within that class.

Comment: @BrianJ public static GeoCoordinate MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0); define in your App.xaml.cs file.

Comment: Okay so I used your solution and defined MyGeoPosition outside of that method scope and it worked, but how do I load the pushpins back onto the map? At present all this code does is retrieve the coordinate data.

Comment: Wouldn't you just call DrawPushPin() again after retrieving the MyGeoPosition coordinate?

Comment: Yes I was thinking that, will debug this now..One more question,the code in OnNavigatedTo is called twice in the app to give two sets of coordinates so am I overwriting the MyGeoPosition variable in my implementation? Or will each set of coordinates be added to a list in settings?

Comment: Also to call the DrawPushPin() I need to pass a pushPinName, is there a way of adding this string along with the `MyGeoPosition` to be saved to app settings and retrieved?